# Rails 4 not deploying to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

Hi I have a Rails 4 application with Devise, Cancan and Rolify. I was able to deploy it to Heroku before and I am not sure what has changed but I get an error.

I am using ENV variables in my application.yml file and I am pretty sure it has something to do with that and the asset pipeline.

If I add `config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false` to my application.rb and run `heroku labs:enable user-env-compile -a myapp` it works, but I would rather figure out how to avoid doing that.

Running `heroku config` displays all the ENV variables correctly also.

I guess my questions is what do those two commands above do, and what could be the error and I can push without them.

Thank you, the stack trace below:

```
-----> Ruby app detected
-----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.1.0
-----> Installing dependencies using 1.5.2
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
       Using rake (10.1.1)
       Using i18n (0.6.9)
       Using minitest (4.7.5)
       Using multi_json (1.8.4)
       Using tzinfo (0.3.38)
       Using erubis (2.7.0)
       Using builder (3.1.4)
       Using rack (1.5.2)
       Using mime-types (1.25.1)
       Using atomic (1.1.14)
       Using polyglot (0.3.3)
       Using arel (4.0.1)
       Using activerecord-deprecated_finders (1.0.3)
       Using bcrypt-ruby (3.1.2)
       Using sass (3.2.14)
       Using cancan (1.6.10)
       Using coffee-script-source (1.7.0)
       Using execjs (2.0.2)
       Using thor (0.18.1)
       Using orm_adapter (0.5.0)
       Using hike (1.2.3)
       Using bundler (1.5.2)
       Using tilt (1.4.1)
       Using json (1.8.1)
       Using pg (0.17.1)
       Using rails_stdout_logging (0.0.3)
       Using rails_serve_static_assets (0.0.2)
       Using rolify (3.4.0)
       Using rack-test (0.6.2)
       Using treetop (1.4.15)
       Using coffee-script (2.2.0)
       Using thread_safe (0.1.3)
       Using warden (1.2.3)
       Using bootstrap-sass (3.1.0.0)
       Using sprockets (2.10.1)
       Using uglifier (2.4.0)
       Using rails_12factor (0.0.2)
       Using activesupport (4.0.2)
       Using actionpack (4.0.2)
       Using jbuilder (1.5.3)
       Using railties (4.0.2)
       Using sprockets-rails (2.0.1)
       Using activemodel (4.0.2)
       Using mail (2.5.4)
       Using simple_form (3.0.1)
       Using activerecord (4.0.2)
       Using coffee-rails (4.0.1)
       Using devise (3.2.2)
       Using sass-rails (4.0.1)
       Using actionmailer (4.0.2)
       Using jquery-rails (3.1.0)
       Using turbolinks (2.2.1)
       Using rails (4.0.2)
       Using figaro (0.7.0)
       Your bundle is complete!
       Gems in the groups development and test were not installed.
       It was installed into ./vendor/bundle
       Bundle completed (0.70s)
       Cleaning up the bundler cache.
-----> Writing config/database.yml to read from DATABASE_URL
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
       Running: rake assets:precompile
       rake aborted!
       could not connect to server: Connection refused
       Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
       TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
       /tmp/build_0a6bfc05-e06f-490f-b6ce-b44782a18da0/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:831:in `initialize'
       /tmp/build_0a6bfc05-e06f-490f-b6ce-b44782a18da0/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:831:in `new'
       /tmp/build_0a6bfc05-e06f-490f-b6ce-b44782a18da0/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:831:in `connect'
       /tmp/build_0a6bfc05-e06f-490f-b6ce-b44782a18da0/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:548:in `initialize'
       /tmp/build_0a6bfc05-e06f-490f-b6ce-b44782a18da0/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:41:in `new'
       /tmp/build_0a6bfc05-e06f-490f-b6ce-b44782a18da0/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:41:in `postgresql_connection'
       /tmp/build_0a6bfc05-e06f-490f-b6ce-b44782a18da0/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:440:in `new_connection'
       /tmp/build_0a6bfc05-e06f-490f-b6ce-b44782a18da0/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:450:in `checkout_new_connection'
       /tmp/build_0a6bfc05-e06f-490f-b6ce-b44782a18da0/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:421:in `acquire_connection'
       /tmp/build_0a6bfc05-e06f-490f-b6ce-b44782a18da0/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:356:in `block in checkout'
       /tmp/build_0a6bfc05-e06f-490f-b6ce-b44782a18da0/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:355:in `checkout'
       /tmp/build_0a6bfc05-e06f-490f-b6ce-b44782a18da0/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:265:in `block in connection'
       /tmp/build_0a6bfc05-e06f-490f-b6ce-b44782a18da0/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:264:in `connection'
       /tmp/build_0a6bfc05-e06f-490f-b6ce-b44782a18da0/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:546:in `retrieve_connection'
       /tmp/build_0a6bfc05-e06f-490f-b6ce-b44782a18da0/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:79:in `retrieve_connection'
       /tmp/build_0a6bfc05-e06f-490f-b6ce-b44782a18da0/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:53:in `connection'
       /tmp/build_0a6bfc05-e06f-490f-b6ce-b44782a18da0/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:203:in `table_exists?'
       /tmp/build_0a6bfc05-e06f-490f-b6ce-b44782a18da0/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rolify-3.4.0/lib/rolify/configure.rb:48:in `block in sanity_check'
       /tmp/build_0a6bfc05-e06f-490f-b6ce-b44782a18da0/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rolify-3.4.0/lib/rolify/configure.rb:46:in `each'
       /tmp/build_0a6bfc05-e06f-490f-b6ce-b44782a18da0/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rolify-3.4.0/lib/rolify/configure.rb:46:in `sanity_check'
       /tmp/build_0a6bfc05-e06f-490f-b6ce-b44782a18da0/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rolify-3.4.0/lib/rolify/configure.rb:7:in `configure'
       /tmp/build_0a6bfc05-e06f-490f-b6ce-b44782a18da0/config/initializers/rolify.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
       /tmp/build_0a6bfc05-e06f-490f-b6ce-b44782a18da0/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load'
       /tmp/build_0a6bfc05-e06f-490f-b6ce-b44782a18da0/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `block in load'
       /tmp/build_0a6bfc05-e06f-490f-b6ce-b44782a18da0/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
       /tmp/build_0a6bfc05-e06f-490f-b6ce-b44782a18da0/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load'
       /tmp/build_0a6bfc05-e06f-490f-b6ce-b44782a18da0/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:609:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
       /tmp/build_0a6bfc05-e06f-490f-b6ce-b44782a18da0/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:608:in `each'
       /tmp/build_0a6bfc05-e06f-490f-b6ce-b44782a18da0/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:608:in `block in <class:Engine>'
       /tmp/build_0a6bfc05-e06f-490f-b6ce-b44782a18da0/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
       /tmp/build_0a6bfc05-e06f-490f-b6ce-b44782a18da0/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
       /tmp/build_0a6bfc05-e06f-490f-b6ce-b44782a18da0/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
       /tmp/build_0a6bfc05-e06f-490f-b6ce-b44782a18da0/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
       /tmp/build_0a6bfc05-e06f-490f-b6ce-b44782a18da0/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
       /tmp/build_0a6bfc05-e06f-490f-b6ce-b44782a18da0/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
       /tmp/build_0a6bfc05-e06f-490f-b6ce-b44782a18da0/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/application.rb:215:in `initialize!'
       /tmp/build_0a6bfc05-e06f-490f-b6ce-b44782a18da0/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
       /tmp/build_0a6bfc05-e06f-490f-b6ce-b44782a18da0/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
       /tmp/build_0a6bfc05-e06f-490f-b6ce-b44782a18da0/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
       /tmp/build_0a6bfc05-e06f-490f-b6ce-b44782a18da0/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `block in require'
       /tmp/build_0a6bfc05-e06f-490f-b6ce-b44782a18da0/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
       /tmp/build_0a6bfc05-e06f-490f-b6ce-b44782a18da0/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
       /tmp/build_0a6bfc05-e06f-490f-b6ce-b44782a18da0/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/application.rb:189:in `require_environment!'
       /tmp/build_0a6bfc05-e06f-490f-b6ce-b44782a18da0/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/application.rb:250:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
       /tmp/build_0a6bfc05-e06f-490f-b6ce-b44782a18da0/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.0.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:54:in `block (2 levels) in define'
       Tasks: TOP => environment
       (See full trace by running task with --trace)
 !
 !     Precompiling assets failed.
 !

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app
```

FIX:
Turns out the rolify gem was updated between the last time I pushed to Heroku and now and it broke the precompiling. He fixed it on his master, but not going to update until next release.

Copy and paste the `rolify/lib/rolify/configure.rb` code into your gem code until it is fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your application relies on having its environment present to boot. As the [Heroku documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline) states:

*"When deploying if you see something similar to the following:*

```
could not connect to server: Connection refused
Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port xxxx?
```

*This means that your app is attempting to connect to the database as part of rake assets:precompile. Because the config vars are not present in the environment and this is the mechanism the Heroku uses to configure your database connection, the command is failing. You should be able to see the same error by running this command:"*

```
env -i GEM_PATH=$GEM_PATH \
       PATH=$PATH \
       DATABASE_URL=postgres://user:pass@127.0.0.1/dbname \
       /bin/sh -c 'bundle exec rake --trace  assets:precompile'
```

As for the solution:

*"You must fix it by not relying on environment variables and the database to be present at precompile time."*

Comment: Yes I saw that, but what is 'precompile time'? Does seeding the db happen an precompile time? When I ran that command I got 'FATAL:  role "user" does not exist' and I think I refer to that only when I seed the db with an admin user.

Comment: I don't mean to be flip, but "precompile time" is the time you're precompiling your assets. When that task is running, something is trying to connect to the database. You need to figure out what that is.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, this is a problem with asset compilation, did you read [this blog post ?](http://blog.genuitytech.com/2012/01/31/heroku-labs-and-user-env-compile/)
My understanding would be that you could also pre-compiled the assets locally :

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

You can also refer to this [heroku help page](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline)